# How establish Scalatest in a Play project with intelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework, intellij-idea, scalatest

I search since a few days a solution to make unit tests with ScalaTest framework, and I didn't find the right solution to make it work...
I've searched in the official website, many tutorials on the net... But nothing.

Any tutorials or tips ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: The [play tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTest) covers testing. You should be able to write your tests in IntelliJ, but will need to run the tests from within the play framework.

Comment: I try to add the Scalatest library without success.. @ggovan I'll read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an example of ScalaTest being used in a Play project, you can look at the source for the ScalaTest.org website itself:

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-website

ScalaTest.org is so simple (just HTML text mostly) that there are no tests as yet, but there are some example test classes here:

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-website/tree/master/test

The one-line change required to the sbt build file to add ScalaTest to the project is here:

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-website/blob/master/project/Build.scala

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for this links, I'll test !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a couple of tips.

1. Use IntelliJ for code editing, but use Play itself (command line) for running tests and compiling the project. If you have the server running, refreshing the browser will automatically recompile any changes you've made within intelliJ, and compile errors will show up in the browser as well. You can also do `~compile` or `~test`, which will continuously run (compile/test) as make changes to the code base, which is nice as well.
2. Play comes built in with support for Specs2, but if you want to use ScalaTest, then simply add it to the dependencies.
3. I'm not sure about the newest version of scalatest, but I've noticed strange output from my tests because they are conducted asynchronously. You can add a settings to `build.sbt` to make the tests run synchronously:

   parallelExecution in Test := false

Comment: I know that Play has a test command, but I'm a little lost when I develop without IDE.

Comment: @Azuken, it will take a little time to learn the interactive prompt of Play!, but you'll be far more productive as a result.